# Create array of JSON object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a PHP API file whichs encodes an array in JSON and then I retrieve the JSON data in my jQuery file to dynamically create elements.

I need to create an array from the JSON I received, so I can acces the received data whenever I want instead of making a new API call and then iterate trough the results....

How would I create a jQuery array to acces the data anywhere in the jQuery code?

My PHP array:
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){

```
$ids = array();
$namen = array();
$brouwerijen = array();
$types = array();
$gistingen = array();
$percs = array();
$inkoop_prijzen = array();
$biertjes = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $naam = $row['naam'];
    $brouwerij = $row['bouwerij'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    $gisting = $row['gisting'];
    $perc = $row['perc'];
    $inkoop_prijs = $row['inkoop_prijs'];

    $ids[] = $id;
    $namen[] = $naam;
    $brouwerijen[] = $brouwerij;
    $types[] = $type;
    $gistingen[] = $gisting;
    $percs[] = $perc;
    $inkoop_prijzen[] = $inkoop_prijs;

}   

for($i=0; $i < count($ids); $i++){

    $biertjes[] = array("id"=>$ids[$i], "naam"=>$namen[$i], "brouwerij"=>$brouwerijen[$i], "type"=>$types[$i], "gisting"=>$gistingen[$i], "perc"=>$percs[$i], "inkoop_prijs"=>$inkoop_prijzen[$i]);

}

echo json_encode($biertjes);


}
```

What I tried to do in jQuery but didn't work (the biertjes.push line):

```
var biertjes = [];
$.ajax({
    url :   "action-api.php",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success :   function(data){ 
        console.log(data);

        var html = '<table style="width:100%"> <tr> <th>Edit</th> <th>Info</th> <th>Delete</th> <th>Naam</th> <th>Percentage</th> </tr>';

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            html+='<tr><td><div class="edit"><img src="img/edit.png"/></div></td>';
            html+='<td><div class="info"><img src="img/info.png"/></div></td>';
            html+='<td><div class="delete"><img src="img/delete.png"/></div></td>';
            html+='<td>'+item.naam+'</td>';
            html+='<td>'+item.perc+'</td></tr>';
            biertjes.push(["id", item.id]);
        });

        html+='</table>'
        container.append(html).css(tableCss());
    },  
});
```

Comment: I think you need `biertjes.push({"id": item.id});`, Why can't `biertjes =  data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know for sure as you have not posted a sample of the JSON, but...

From your ajax call we can see that you expect a JSON response therefore data is going to become a plain JS object. If your JSON is something like this:

```
[{
    "id": 111,
    "naam": "AAAA",
    "perc": 111.11
}, {
    "id": 222,
    "naam": "BBBB",
    "perc": 222.22
}, {
    "id": 333,
    "naam": "CCCC",
    "perc": 333.33
}]
```

Then the data variable will be JS array. Therefore you can do

```
console.log(data[0].id) // 111
console.log(data[1].naam) // 'BBBB'

for (var i=0; i < data.length(); i = i + 1){
    console.log('Element ' + i + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(data[i]))
}
```

Conclusion - no requirement to create a separate array, just use data. If you need to access the array outside the ajax success function then:

```
biertjes = data
```